# How to enable test mode when deploying Windows 10 wim image with Dism?

Tags: deployment, windows-10, dism

I am upgrading about 200 machines in my lab from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and as part of the upgrade, I am also converting the file system on the machines to GPT.

I am doing this as an automated process with WinPE images that are loaded from my PXE server. In the image, there is a script that formats the hard drive with Diskpart, creates EFI boot partition and the OS partition, deploys the image like this:

*dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:M:\Images[image file name].wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:*

And after deployment, it runs *bcdboot W:\Windows* command so the PC will boot into Win10, then reboots the PC from hard drive with freshly deployed OS image.

Now it works fine, except for one problem:

For our needs (this is a testing lab), we use a proprietary driver, that is unsigned, and thus needs to run Windows in Test Mode.

With Win7 and MBR, I didn't have this problem, because I used Ghost to take the whole HDD image and just dump it on the HDD, without needing to overwrite the boot script.

Now, the *bcdboot W:\Windows* disables the test mode, and I am getting a BSOD when loading the said driver, because of it.

How can I enable Test Mode when deploying with DISM, before booting into OS, using command line? Is there a way to do it with *bcdboot* command somehow?

I have to automate it, because I need to do it on 200 machines.

The OS is Windows 10 RS4 x64 Enterprise.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: this question should be asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, asked there too

Answer (score 0):

Found sort of solution.

If test mode is not enabled, then Windows 10 just starts with the unsigned drivers disabled, unlike 7, which gave BSOD on startup.

So the test mode can just be re-enabled after that with:

*bcdedit /set testsigning on* and *shutdown -r -t 0* to restart the machine

Still would like to know if there is an option to re-enable test mode before booting into Windows.